# R: Inversa de "na.omit"

Tags: r

Tengo un archivo con filas que contienen perdidos y otras que están completas. Quiero un archivo nuevo solo con las filas que tienen perdidos.  Es decir, lo contrario de na.omit
Ejemplo:

```
Archivo Completo
Nombre    Edad    Sexo
Luis       20      M
María      NA      NA
Juan       NA      M
Elena      22      F

Archivo nuevo
Nombre    Edad    Sexo
María      NA      NA
Juan       NA      M
```

Answer (score 1):

En R la función `is.na` permite obtener un vector lógico con `TRUE` en los casos de valores perdidos. Al anidar la función `any` con la función is.na se verifica si un vector determinado tiene algún valor perdido, la función `which` permite identificar la posición de estos valores, mean el porcentaje de `NA` y `sum` la cantidad de `NA`:

```
> is.na(x)        # Vector lógico con T==NA
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

> any(is.na(x))   # TRUE = hay al menos un valor NA
[1] TRUE

> anyNA(x)        # Alternativa a lo anterior
[1] TRUE

> which(is.na(x)) # Indica las coordenadas donde están los NA
[1] 6 8

> mean(is.na(x))  # Porcentaje de valores NA
[1] 0.25

> sum(is.na(x))   # Cantidad de valores perdidos en el vector
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Como hay que buscar filas que cumplan la condición deseada, la forma clásica es usar `apply()` por fila:

```
filas_con_na <- apply(df, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
```

El 1 indica que se aplicará la función por fila. Luego simplemente habrá que seleccionarlas:

```
df[filas_con_na, ]
```

O bien, podemos sumar los `NA` por fila mediante `rowSums()` y filtrar filas dónde este valor sea mayor a 0

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df))>0, ]
```